# Движение видимой области на экране

Tags: java, android, камера

Подскажите пожалуйста, как  в android реализовывается движение видимой области на экране, что бы пользователь  могут двигать экран влево если провёл по экрану.

Comment: Возможно, layout должен растягиваться по размеру экрана, но не трогать layer содержимого, а содержимое (например, произвольный компонент из какого нибудь image), должно быть фиксированного размера, и в разы больше этого самого окошка layout-а. Далее, обрабатываем события нажатий, и перемещаем положение содержимого. Не уверен, есть ли в андроиде AbsoluteLayout, но, он был бы самым простым решением

Comment: А вообще, вам достаточно отнаследовать любой слой и переписать его поведение на абсолютное позиционирование содержимого.

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Как пример того что вы хотите: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html и http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/scrollview.php